# rdlc reporting don't show values when groep row exists

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

I have the following table in my rdlc report

testSubject | (settingUnit) | (BrochureValue) | (TestMethod) - Group 1
TestSetting | SettingUnit | BrochureValue | TestMethod - Group 2

When there is an testSetting in testSubject i want the () values not displayed in the table. Is this possible in RDLC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use expression to show hide value conditionally in each column:

```
= IIF(Fields!testSubject.Value = "testSetting","",Fields!settingUnit.Value)
```

You can completely hide row also. for that you have to use expression in row visibility.

```
= IIF(Fields!testSubject.Value = "testSetting",false,true)
```

Comment: My testSubject and testSetting are dataset data. It's not just a string value

Comment: I use two of them. In that dataset i have two tables. But for the table i described above i only use one

Comment: @user3702149 sorry not able to understand what u are trying to explain. does testSubject and testSetting are values particular column from tow different rows of table?

Comment: I think i need this. When testSetting != "" then dont show first row (groep 1) settingUnit 

if testSetting = "" show first row (groep 1) settingUnit

Comment: My DataSet looks like this:

testsubject  |  testsetting
test         |  a
test         |  b
test 1       |
test 2       |  c
test 2       |  d

When testsetting != "" then don't show settingunit in groep 1